# how can insert all value from GridView to sql

Tags: c#, gridview

I am using the below click event to update database:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection(CS))
    { 
        con2.Open();
        for (int y = 0; y < GridView1.Rows.Count - 0; y++)
        { 
            SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("insertCityNameHeadTBL", con2);
            cmd2.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityName", GridView1.Rows[y].Cells[1].Text);        
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

         }
     }
 }
```

I want to Insert all values from GridView to sql database

Comment: That's not how grids work. Grids are for *displaying* data. They don't contain the data or act as DTOs. Find the original data that you used to create the grid instead of trying to convert a grid's text content into data. Where did the grid's data come from? What code did you use to load it?

Comment: thanks for replay but i forget create store procured

Comment: now it working..